# Quotas View: Queries Per Day Graph Not Showing Any Data

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

For over one week now the graph over the amount of quota points used per day by my application has only shown "No data is available for the selected time frame" (30 days) on this page: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas. I also found the same view in the cloud console, it does not load there either: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas. The "Queries per minute (3 hr average)" graph on the same page is working and shows data, as well as multiple other view in both the developer and cloud console. (two of them is /iam-admin/quotas and /apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/metrics)

More proofs that there is data to show for this last week is that I received feedback from users about the quota limit has been reached and I tried generating some traffic my self and even caught the quota limit exceeded exception while debugging two days ago.

I tried using different browsers and from different devices but I get the same result on all of them. How can I access the quota usage per day over the last month?

Comment: I suggest to file a bug report to [Google](http://issuetracker.google.com/). Then link back that page here such that other interested SO users to follow it easily.

Comment: Thank you @stvar for that link, I tried looking for where to report this and landed on the following page telling me to ask here on StackOverflow... https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support?hl=en Here is the issue tracker link: https://issuetracker.google.com/160361448

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly an answer, since I agree that this is a bug which Google needs to address. It's just something of a workaround to get *some* data about what's being used.

You can see quota use data for the current day and 7-day peak data by using the Quotas page of the IAM & Admin section on the Google Cloud Platform console. It does not appear to offer any kind of historical data view, however.

1. Get to the Cloud Platform Console and select the Project you want to get data for.
2. Open the Navigation menu (≡ symbol on the top left).
3. Select `IAM & Admin > Quotas`
4. If necessary for your Project, use the `Filter table` field at the top to restrict to entries related to the `YouTube Data API V3`.

Note: You can also reach this from the APIs & Services > Quotas page, using the link in the information notice at the top.